# Docker "permission denied" in container

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, containers, virtualization

I am trying to run a docker image by

```
docker run  -it -v $PWD/examples:/home/user/examples image
```

which should make `$PWD/examples` in the host accessible in the container. However when I `ls` in the container, it keeps giving me

```
ls: cannot access 'examples': Permission denied
```

I have tried the answers for similar questions, the `z/Z` option and `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /host/path/` and `run --privileged`, but neither of them have any effect in my case.
In fact, the `z` option appears to work for the first time `ls`, but when I issue `ls` the second time it is denied again.

Comment: What image are you running?

Comment: Maybe there is a `USER` instruction in Dockerfile, and that user is not allowed to access `examples` from another user? You can test with `--user=root` to supersede a possible `USER`.

Comment: @BrunoGL it's the official pre-built image of some software..

Comment: @mviereck Thanks, that appears to work! is there a way to fix it instead of a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments it turned out that there is probably a `USER` instruction in the `Dockerfile` of the image. This user is not allowed to access `examples` due to file access permissions of `examples`.

---

It is possible to supersede `USER` with docker run option `--user`.

A quick and dirty solution is to run with `--user=root` to allow arbitrary access.
Be aware that files written as `root` in container to folder `examples` will be owned by `root`.

A better solution is to look for owner of `examples`, call him `foo`. Specify its user id and group id to have exactly the same user in container:

```
docker run --user $(id -u foo):$(id -g foo)  imagename
```

---

Another possible solution is to allow arbitray access with `chmod 666 examples` or `chmod 644 examples`, but most probably you don't want that.

---

The best way would be to look at the Dockerfile and check the purpose of `USER` instruction.

- If it only serves the purpose of avoiding root in container, the best way is to use `--user=foo` or more precisely `--user=$(id -u foo):$(id -g foo)`.
- If something in Dockerfile/image relies on specific `USER`, it may be the best to change access permissions of `examples`.
- If you have access to the Dockerfile, you may adjust it to fit your host user/the owner of `examples`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the container as privileged:

```
sudo docker run --privileged=true -itd -v /***/***:/***  ubuntu bash
```

> for example: sudo docker run --privileged=true -itd -v
> /home/willie:/wille ubuntu bash